# Use case of try-except-else statement

Tags: python, django, try-except

What is the point of using an `else` clause if there is a `return` instruction in the `except` clause?

```
def foo():
    try:
        # Some code
    except:
        # Some code
        return
    else:
        # Some code
```

I'm asking this question because the Django documentation does it at [some point](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial04/), in the `vote()` function. Considering that the `return` instruction in the `except` clause will anyway stop the execution of the function, why did they use an `else` clause to isolate the code that should only be executed if no exception was raised? They could have just omitted the `else` clause entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is **no** exception in the `try:` suite, then the `else:` suite is executed. In other words, only if there is an actual exception is the `except:` suite reached and the `return` statement used.

In my view, the `return` statement is what is redundant here; a `pass` would have sufficed. I'd use an `else:` suite to a `try` when there is additional code that should *only* be executed if no exception is raised, but could raise exceptions itself that should not be caught.

You are right that a `return` in the `except` clause makes *using* an `else:` for that section of code somewhat redundant. The whole suite could be de-dented and the `else:` *line* removed:

```
def foo():
    try:
        # Some code
    except:
        # Some code
        return

    # Some code
```

Comment: I think the point is that they could have just omitted `else` entirely. It's stylistic.

Comment: @katrielalex: only if the `pass` is not just illustrative. Otherwise, `else: pass` is **always** redundant, whatever the context.

Comment: Right, of course `pass` is redundant. I meant that deleting `else` and dedenting `pass` would also be semantically equivalent.

Comment: @katrielalex: It would *not*, not if there is more code following the `try` block. Ah, which the `return` would skip, is what you mean.

Comment: I updated the question. I would also think that the `else` clause is purely stylistic.

Comment: @user3084451: I've already updated the answer, it is indeed stylistic.

Comment: I agree. So finally, is it better in any way to use an `else` clause even when there is a `return` instruction in the `except` clause or it's definitely useless?

Comment: @user3084451: From the POV of the resulting bytecode, it is useless. The only difference it makes is in self-documentation, perhaps. But I find the `return` statement clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs: 
`The use of the else clause is better than adding additional code to the try clause because it avoids accidentally catching an exception that wasn’t raised by the code being protected by the try ... except statement.`
http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions